# Set up users roles and permissions in parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, permissions, roles

looking to set up user permissions in parse.com. i have a know list of users in my user "table". i want to lock down the app for supervisors(role) only view most tables and modify a few. have managers(role) to view almost all tables and modify most. Administrators to view and modify all.

after searching for days i only see code to modify roles and permissions. what is the purpose using code if the roles and permissions are only setup once? or would someone please explain how to set up roles and permissions in the data window online.
thanks for your help

I get this error on the save line: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_Role/24EHbUyDzv 404 (Not Found)

my sample code for utility:

```
// First create a pointer to the object of yourClassName
var user = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var pointer = new user();
pointer.id = "aL5dfXQsRO";

// Now you can add the pointer to the relation
query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role); 
query.equalTo("name", "manager"); 
query.first ( { 
      success: function(object) { 
      object.relation("users").add(pointer); 
      object.save();
      //response.success("The user has been authorized.");
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's two options to get the job done.

1) Write some single-purpose code to set the roles. Roles are a type of relation, so you will have to create them as such. [Here is a quote from a Parse engineer on the subject:](https://www.parse.com/questions/a-guide-for-using-data-browser)

> To add objects to a relation column, you need to use the client SDKs
>   or REST API.

2) [The workaround described here.](https://parse.com/questions/adding-existing-rows-to-a-relation-via-the-data-browser) The gist of it is, you can export your table's data, modify data for the roles, and then import the updates back into Parse. This will allow you to manually set the roles without having to write single-purpose code.

Edit: Here's your code sample and correction

```
// First create a pointer to the object of yourClassName
var UserClass = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var userPointer = new UserClass();
userPointer.id = "aL5dfXQsRO";

// Now you can add the pointer to the relation
query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role); 
query.equalTo("name", "manager"); 
query.first ( { 
    success: function(object) { 
        object.relation("users").add(userPointer); 
        object.save();
```

Comment: Thank for your help.      i have built a utility iwth SDK to do this and have not been able to get it to work. I have used maybe six or more different ways and none have worked. i have down loaded table in JSON and i have not been able to open or extract from ZIP.

Comment: Thank for your help.      i have built a utility iwth SDK to do this and have not been able to get it to work. I have used maybe six or more different ways and none have worked. i have down loaded table in JSON and i have not been able to open or extract from ZIP.     Error i get is "  post bad request"

Comment: code is :              query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
                            query.equalTo("name", "manager");
                            query.first ( {
                                success: function(object) {
                                  object.relation("users").add("aL5dfXQsRO");
                                  object.save();

Comment: When posting code like that, edit the OP instead of squeezing it into a comment so it's easier to read. I'm not sure why you're not able to open the zip file, it works just fine for me right now. Is it the zip file you can't open or are you having trouble editing the JSON? Lastly, the issue with your code is that you are trying to add the string `"aL5dfXQsRO"` as a relation. You need to be adding a ***pointer*** to the object. See my edit

Comment: Thank you so much, in the past, I have downloaded json files from parse and i have opened and edited them fine. this may be because my computer is running very slow and showing signs of issues with all the programs i have running. I will look into it and clean up the computer issues first.

Comment: i have added my code above and the error received. Thank you for your help and where do you suggest that i can learn more. i seem to know a lot to get started but not enough to finish. by the way the error code shows the ID of "24EHbUyDzv" that does exist as the manager Role.

Comment: Maybe i dont have my Role collection set up right. i have a relation column  "user" and a pointer column "user" to be safe.

Comment: The code looks solid assuming that the objectIds are correct. My guess is it's an issue with the structure of the Role table. Try taking a look at this http://blog.parse.com/announcements/lets-role/

Comment: I have used your code and i get an error of "POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_Role/6PyusIj8aE 400 (Bad Request)"  the role ID is the correct roleID for the Manager Role. any ideas?