# setup cloud code for Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have gone through the instruction found on Parse.com to setup Cloud code. I downloaded exe file as instructed in 1. It seems like there is a step missing before step 2.

When i run "parse new" in the command prompt i get "not recognized as an internal or external command". What am i missing? How do i install/use cloud code?

> Get the Parse tool
>
> 1. The Parse command line tool for Windows is available here. Download
>      the Windows executable named: parse.exe at this link. Note that this
>      is not an installer, it is just a plain Windows executable.
>
>    Set up a Cloud Code directory.
> 2. From the Command Prompt, run the command parse new and follow
>      instructions. In this quickstart we'll see how to set up your server
>      code on Heroku. Please read docs for more details.

Comment: Try closing and opening a new command line window. It's possible that the environment variable to locate the Parse CLI will not be updated until you open a new command line. Also, do you receive the same error when you type `parse help`?

Comment: i have closed and opened a few times. Yes "parse help" has the same response. I thought i was missing steps between download link and try commands in the command prompt. what do you think?

Comment: Hm that's strange, maybe it could be a permissions issue. Try running the installer again with admin privileges. If that's still causing trouble, it's probably worth reporting it as a bug to Parse. I've only used the Parse CLI on mac, but it seems like it should be just as simple for windows

Comment: The instructions say that it is a command line app not an installer. After download what do i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded the parse CLI on my Windows desktop to figure it out and I believe I've found your solution.

You need to open up a standard command line on windows and then navigate to where you have stored parse.exe. Once the command line is at the same directory as the exe, you will be able to run `parse new` and any of the other CLI commands.

For example, you could do the following:

- Hit the Windows key (or start menu) and search "cmd" then hit enter to open the command line
- Navigate to where `parse.exe` is located. If it's on your desktop, it could be something along the lines of `cd C:\Users\<name>\Desktop`
- `parse help`, `parse new` and so on should now work from this directory

The documentation feels a bit vague and could use some clarification for the Windows platform. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you , that is what i needed. i was sure there were essential steps i was missing. i am now writing code. thanks again.

Comment: do you have the knowledge to answer this one,  http://stackoverflow.com/q/33243368/5253603 @Russell

Comment: Happy to help and just posted an answer. Take a look :)